# "cd" has no effect when executing series of commands

Tags: rust, cmd, cd

I want to make a small CLI kinda project where I can execute series of commands. So, I wrote this code:

```
let commands = ["cd C:\\Users\\MegaMind\\Documents\\dynamodb_local_latest","dir","echo rust"];
for ccc in &commands {
    let rc = Command::new("cmd")
        .arg("/C")
        .arg(ccc)
        .output()
        .expect("there was an error");

    io::stdout().write_all(&rc.stdout).unwrap();
    // io::stdout().write_all(&rc.stderr).unwrap();
}
```

It seems like it runs the `dir` command within the source code's folder instead of `C:\\Users\\MegaMind\\Documents\\dynamodb_local_latest`. How can I get the `cd` to take effect?

Answer (score 5):

The working directory applies on a per-process basis. Each `Command` is a separate process. The `cd` command changes the working directory *for that process*, and then *that process exits* and the record of that directory change is gone. Then you launch a new process (the one running `dir`) and it's still using the *original* working directory.

If you want to set the working directory for any given child command, just [use the `current_dir` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.current_dir) when setting it up or (depending on what your needs are) you may want to [change the Rust process's working directory](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.set_current_dir.html) (which will be inherited by child processes when not overridden).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but lets say, I want to dynamically keep changing the directory to something else, do I have to keep checking for the `cd` command and keep on calling the `current_dir` method? & BTW, its not necessary that I have to use the `std::process::Command`. if there's any other crate that can do that, please feel free to suggest. Thanks

Comment: @xuka Yes, you would have to keep checking for `cd` indeed. This is because `cd` is not a command for your CLI to execute, it's a command to change the state of the CLI process itself (changing its working directory).

Comment: @xuka: Given that you're writing your own CLI, looking for the `cd` command and changing the Rust process's working directory globally when you see it would make sense. You still need to handle `cd` specially, but you don't necessarily need to use `current_dir` for every command invoked. But yes, as Matthieu says, there is no way to actually *run* `cd` and have it have *any* lingering effect on future process launches; you have to handle it within your Rust process in some way to make it persist.

Comment: I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation of the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which *Rust* uses here to start `cmd.exe` and which `explorer.exe` or `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` or `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe` or `java.exe` or `python.exe` or ... (any other Windows executable capable starting another executable) uses also to start another executable with function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` being `null` or pointing to a directory path string.